# Operator precedence issue involving comparison followed by ternary expression with no parentheses

Tags: php, conditional-statements, conditional-operator, operator-precedence

So I can not understand why code given below does work like it works.

```
$values = [
    [
      'key' => 'value',
      'key2' => 'value2'
    ]
];

function filter($values, $flag = false) {
    return array_filter(
        $values,
        function ($record) use ($flag) {
            return $record['not_existing_key'] == 'not_existing_value'
                && $record['not_existing_key2'] == $flag ? '' : 'not_existing_value2';
        }
    );
}

print_r(filter($values));
```

Output of code above is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => value
            [key2] => value
        )

)
```

As I understand `&&` operator in PHP, second condition should not even be handled if first one is false (which obviously is in this case), however if we remove the second part of the condition it works as excepted - It does not return any value.
Right now, somehow this function does return value.

Can someone explain how does it work?

Answer (score 3):

You have an [operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) issue: `&&` and `==` have higher precedence than `?:` so your code is being interpreted as:

```
($record['not_existing_key'] == 'not_existing_value'
&& $record['not_existing_key2'] == $flag) ? '' : 'not_existing_value2';
```

which since the first condition is false, evaluates to `'not_existing_value2'` which is considered `true` in a boolean context.

You need to add parentheses to get the evaluation ordering you want:

```
return $record['not_existing_key'] == 'not_existing_value'
    && $record['not_existing_key2'] == ($flag ? '' : 'not_existing_value2');
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/dGqBW)